# Decode data returned by programSubscribe

Tags: anchor, transactions, websocket, data, decode

I can't figure out how to decode the 'data' received when subscribed (via websocket) to the Jupiter Limit Order Program (jupoNjAxXgZ4rjzxzPMP4oxduvQsQtZzyknqvzYNrNu). I'm using the program's IDL.

This is the websocket response, and within it, the data (in bold) that I'm trying to decode:

> {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'programNotification', 'params':
> {'result': {'context': {'slot': 250801856}, 'value': {'pubkey':
> 'DuAnTiS8bde5TNw8jW6XZJU1GyJoWJJ9KHeC4pejiL3Q', 'account':
> {'lamports': 3083280, **'data':
> ['hq3fuU1WHDPqnxxzMfyMEPa9JCjq67X2o3spTG0Gdvp4XbQH6GvPlMX5+zL0kRGrIMM/JZj8g2wRPikYgawh7ikWk5QBEkTkxvp6877brTo9ZfNqq8l0MbG75MLS9uDkfKYCA0UvXWEBAHQ7pAsAAACA0oPDBgAAAADAqvkBAAAAv+LKJQEAAACDYTApklsbHRdeB4ONoOIm8TNVbJg97hbw/ixdm8pX+b30T+R1Eb7LZc21GToW5aQSkBKVu7lQFJnLKBxmpyjlPY8V5L8RDniH1NaorkTtmsK7xlxc58LILLq1ygI34BMAAAAAAAAAAABmzwauuf+2nYZKxrPSeQkr4RudzlFfQRKUqcyUXrFv8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
> 'base64']**, 'owner': 'jupoNjAxXgZ4rjzxzPMP4oxduvQsQtZzyknqvzYNrNu',
> 'executable': False, 'rentEpoch': 18446744073709551615, 'space':
> 315}}}, 'subscription': 3601673}}

The Python script I'm using to try to decode this data:

```
async def main():
    program_id = Pubkey.from_string("jupoNjAxXgZ4rjzxzPMP4oxduvQsQtZzyknqvzYNrNu") 
    provider = Provider(wallet=Keypair(),connection=AsyncClient('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/','processed'))
    program = await Program.at(
        program_id, provider
    )
    coder = InstructionCoder(program.idl)
    data='hq3fuU1WHDPqnxxzMfyMEPa9JCjq67X2o3spTG0Gdvp4XbQH6GvPlMX5+zL0kRGrIMM/JZj8g2wRPikYgawh7ikWk5QBEkTkxvp6877brTo9ZfNqq8l0MbG75MLS9uDkfKYCA0UvXWEBAHQ7pAsAAACA0oPDBgAAAADAqvkBAAAAv+LKJQEAAACDYTApklsbHRdeB4ONoOIm8TNVbJg97hbw/ixdm8pX+b30T+R1Eb7LZc21GToW5aQSkBKVu7lQFJnLKBxmpyjlPY8V5L8RDniH1NaorkTtmsK7xlxc58LILLq1ygI34BMAAAAAAAAAAABmzwauuf+2nYZKxrPSeQkr4RudzlFfQRKUqcyUXrFv8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
    data=base64.b64decode(data)
    print(data)
    print(coder.parse(data))

    await program.close()    
asyncio.run(main())
```

This is what I get:

```
KeyError: b'\x86\xad\xdf\xb9MV\x1c3'
```

**Could anyone help with this?**

Comment: The `programSubscribe` notification notifies you about accounts owned by the program, not instructions. It's sort of like `getProgramAccounts` data. You'll need to decode the data as account data, not instruction data. I'm not familiar with the Python library so I'm not sure how you'd do that, but hopefully that points you in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you, I will dig into that!